# Replace value in list of dictionary in JSON file

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have a JSON file containing a list of 9000 dictionaries.

Sample

```
[{"auftrags_id":348667,"vertrags_id":11699,"ursprungsauftrag":"",
"umsatz":0.28,"brutto":0.33,"vertrauensschadenhaftpflicht":"",
"stornoreserve":"","umsatzsteuer_betrag":"0.05","netto":0.28,
"steuerpflichtig":"0","art_der_rechnung":"Rechnung","vp_nummer":538},
{"auftrags_id":348668,"vertrags_id":11699,"ursprungsauftrag":"",
"umsatz":0.28,"brutto":0.33,"vertrauensschadenhaftpflicht":"",
"stornoreserve":"","umsatzsteuer_betrag":"0.05","netto":0.28,
"steuerpflichtig":"0","art_der_rechnung":"Rechnung","vp_nummer":538},
{"auftrags_id":349210,"vertrags_id":24894,"ursprungsauftrag":"X",
"umsatz":0.87,"brutto":1.04,"vertrauensschadenhaftpflicht":"X",
"stornoreserve":"X","umsatzsteuer_betrag":"0.17","netto":0.87,
"steuerpflichtig":"0","art_der_rechnung":"Rechnung","vp_nummer":538}]
```

To upload the JSON-File to Postgresql, I need to replace the X with a value accepted as float. I think replacing the value 'X' with '0.0001' in every dictionary would do it. Then there are values with no content, "", I don't know how to handle them,maybe also replacing them with '0.0001', just for purpose of uploading.

Desired output:

```
   [{"auftrags_id":348667,"vertrags_id":11699,"ursprungsauftrag":0.0001,
"umsatz":0.28,"brutto":0.33,"vertrauensschadenhaftpflicht":0.0001,
"stornoreserve":0.0001,"umsatzsteuer_betrag":0.05,"netto":0.28,
"steuerpflichtig":0.0001,"art_der_rechnung":"Rechnung","vp_nummer":538},
{"auftrags_id":348668,"vertrags_id":11699,"ursprungsauftrag":0.0001,
"umsatz":0.28,"brutto":0.33,"vertrauensschadenhaftpflicht":0.0001,
"stornoreserve":0.0001,"umsatzsteuer_betrag":0.05,"netto":0.28,
"steuerpflichtig":0.0001,"art_der_rechnung":"Rechnung","vp_nummer":538},
{"auftrags_id":349210,"vertrags_id":24894,"ursprungsauftrag":0.0001,
"umsatz":0.87,"brutto":1.04,"vertrauensschadenhaftpflicht":0.0001,
"stornoreserve":0.0001,"umsatzsteuer_betrag":0.17,"netto":0.87,
"steuerpflichtig":"0","art_der_rechnung":"Rechnung","vp_nummer":538}]
```

I already have a code to upload the file, but i need to clean the JSON file for Postgresql to accept it. Appreciate any help!

Comment: `sed s/\"X\"/0.0001/g` ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this, don't know what sed means :/, i'm looking for a solution in python

Comment: Why are you looking for solutions in python?

Comment: It's because im still learning python. If there is a way to solve it with python i would like to learn how to do it. But altrough, i'm open to learn everything, how can I apply your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` as suggested in the comment under your question. It is a command for the Linux command line (shell). See an article about Linux shell [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-command-line-interface-introduction-guide) and about the `sed` command [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/).

The Python solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import json  # load the builtin JSON module

JSON_FILE_NAME = "dictionaries.json"  # the name of your file with those dictionaries
RESULT_FILE_NAME = "result.json"  # the name of the file that will be created

# Load the file contents into variable dictionaries
with open(JSON_FILE_NAME, "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
    dictionaries = json.load(file)

result = []

for dictionary in dictionaries:  # loop over the dictionaries
    for key, value in dictionary.items():  # loop over the key and value pairs in the dictionary
        if value in ("", "X"):
            # if the value is an empty string or "X", change it to 0.0001
            dictionary[key] = 0.0001
    # append the dictionary to the result list
    result.append(dictionary)

# save the result to a file
with open(RESULT_FILE_NAME, "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
    json.dump(result, file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and solution :) It worked and I learned how to apply a double `for` loop